# Understanding the meaning of pivot position

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If a matrix has a leading one in every row and column, does that mean that there is only a trivial solution for the null space?

Also, if a matrix does not have a leading one in every row and column, does that mean there is not a solution for every possible solution vector?

Comment: @EricTowers corrected.

Comment: Do you mean the matrix to be in reduced row echelon form?

Comment: @saulspatz yes.

Comment: No. Consider a $1 \times n$ matrix.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I should have said column! let me fix that.

Comment: My answer is based on eigenvalues. Have you seen that in class?

Comment: @Burt A matrix has a trivial nullspace if and only if it has a pivot in every column (of its row echelon form). There is a solution to $Ax = b$ for all $b$ if and only if $A$ has a pivot in every row (of its row echelon form).